Unit test error using 'Vitest, @nuxt/test-utils' (SyntaxError: At least one <template> or <script> is required for each file component. )
Objective:
I want to test an API via useFetch from Vuetify components.
Error occurrence:
To achieve this goal, I've used '@nuxt/test-utils/runtime'.
However, I encountered errors in the logs.
To identify the cause, I've minimized the provided repository.
As a result, it seems that an error occurs when "index.vue" is imported and used.
Previously, I was using import { defineConfig } from "vite"; in vitest.config.ts and there were no errors in the logs at that time.
Both <templage>  <script> are present in index.vue.
Could you please advise me on this.
Targeted Github：https://github.com/motoo1789/nuxt-test-utils_report
Reproduction

Import the Github into your local environment
Run npm install in the environment imported to local
Run npx vitest index

Logs
FAIL  tests/pages/index.test.ts [ tests/pages/index.test.ts ]
SyntaxError: At least one <template> or <script> is required in a single file component.
 ❯ Object.parse$2 [as parse] node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js:1921:7
 ❯ createDescriptor node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:74:43
 ❯ transformMain node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:2367:34
 ❯ TransformContext.transform node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue/dist/index.mjs:2910:16
 ❯ Object.transform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:51172:62
 ❯ loadAndTransform node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:53923:29

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
Serialized Error: { id: 'C:/Users/motoo/report/nuxt-test-utils_report/pages/index.vue', plugin: 'vite:vue', pluginCode: 'const _sfc_main = {}\nimport { createVNode as _createVNode, openBlock as _openBlock, createElementBlock as _createElementBlock } from "vue"\n\nfunction _sfc_render(_ctx, _cache) {\n                                                       \n\n  return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", null, [\n    _createVNode(_component_v_card)\n  ]))\n}\n\n\nimport _export_sfc from \'\u0000plugin-vue:export-helper\'\nexport default /*#__PURE__*/_export_sfc(_sfc_main, [[\'render\',_sfc_render],[\'__file\',"C:/Users/motoo/report/nuxt-test-utils_report/pages/index.vue"]])\n\n/* Vuetify */\nimport { VCard as _component_v_card } from "vuetify/lib/components/VCard/index.mjs"\n\n' }

We have tried to deal with this issue here as a close problem.
The solution to this problem is to remove Vue() from the plugins in 'vitest.config.ts'.
However, I get an error saying to load Vue() first because I am using vitest().
// vitest.config.ts   
import Vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import path from 'path'
import { defineVitestConfig } from '@nuxt/test-utils/config'


export default defineVitestConfig({
  plugins: [
    // Vue(), error
    vuetify(),
  ],
  // and more ...


If you use @nuxt/test-utils, it seems that you do not need to write vue() and vuetify() in the plugin.
I removed the plugins and it works fine.
